# Keep responsive aspect ratio on a CSS animated sprite sheet

Tags: css, responsive-design, sprite-sheet

I have made this animated sprite sheet responsive but it does not keep its aspect ratio when I resize the window. It looks stretched.

How can I make it keep the same aspect ratio when the div is scaled so the animated sprite sheet becomes responsive ?

```
<style>
    .gale-anim{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:url('gale.png');
        background-size:100% 500%;
        animation:fly 0.7s steps(5) infinite;
    }
    @keyframes fly {
        0%{ background-position: 0px 0px; }
        100%{ background-position: 0px -500%; }
    }
</style>

<div style="max-width:556px; max-height:448px;">
    <div class="gale-anim"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you forget the most important part which is the image you are using. Without we cannot help you

Comment: it is just a normal spritesheet with 5 images next to each other you can see it in the code.

Comment: no I can't see in the code ...